# Set an ImageView to fullscreen with icons on it.

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, fullscreen, scenebuilder

There are different Image Views on an other ImageView. Can I set it to Fullscreen with out the other Images changing Position? When i start the Programm the Image stays the same size even tho the Pane is Fullsreen.
My FXML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
 <?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
 <?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="537.0" prefWidth="713.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" type="Pane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="studiprojekt.Studi_Controller">
<children>
  <Button fx:id="buttonBuch" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="88.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#pressButton" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="61.0" />
  <ImageView fx:id="bildAuto" fitHeight="537.0" fitWidth="721.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="file:/C:/Users/buerv/Documents/NetBeansProjects/StudiProjekt/Skyline.JPG" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <ImageView id="bildAuto" fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="43.0" layoutX="210.0" layoutY="97.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="file:/C:/Users/buerv/Documents/NetBeansProjects/StudiProjekt/Icons/contacts-book.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" layoutX="534.0" layoutY="86.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="file:/C:/Users/buerv/Documents/NetBeansProjects/StudiProjekt/Icons/earth-and-laptop.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <ImageView fitHeight="60.0" fitWidth="73.0" layoutX="379.0" layoutY="344.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="file:/C:/Users/buerv/Documents/NetBeansProjects/StudiProjekt/Icons/sedan-car-model.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" layoutX="111.0" layoutY="294.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="file:/C:/Users/buerv/Documents/NetBeansProjects/StudiProjekt/Icons/code-signs-on-laptop-screen.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" layoutX="383.0" layoutY="250.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="file:/C:/Users/buerv/Documents/NetBeansProjects/StudiProjekt/Icons/rectangular-closed-padlock-lock-interface-symbol.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" layoutX="545.0" layoutY="310.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="file:/C:/Users/buerv/Documents/NetBeansProjects/StudiProjekt/Icons/car-chassis.png" />
      </image>
   </ImageView>
</children>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: So do you want to show a `Parent` object full-screen (`StackPane` or similar having numeroues `ImageView` in it) or you want to show the image of an `ImageView` full-screen?

Comment: @DVarga I mean the first solution.

Comment: Your edit improves the question, but it's still really unclear what you're asking. All the locations and sizes of your `ImageView`s are hard coded. So if you full-screen the view, they will stay in the same place relative to the top left of the view. What is it you actually want to happen that's different to that?

Comment: @James_D  Yeah I don't know how to describe it in English but thank you anyway.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to mock up an image of what you want it to look like? Maybe the real problem here is not so much that you don't know how to write the code, but that you don't know how to specify what it is you're trying to code?